# Absolute value inequality, where am I wrong?

Tags: inequality

Tried to solving $|x^2-5x+5|<1$ using the square method, but I don't know what I did wrong:

$$-1<x^2-5x+5<1$$
$$-6<x^2-5x<-4$$
$$-6+\frac{25}{4}<x^2-5x+\frac{25}{4}<-4+\frac{25}{4}$$
$$\frac{25-24}{4}<\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2<\frac{25-16}{4}$$
$$\frac{\pm\sqrt1}{\sqrt4}<\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2}<\frac{\pm\sqrt9}{\sqrt4}$$
$$\frac{\pm1}{2}<x-\frac{5}{2}<\frac{\pm3}{2}$$
$$\frac{5\pm1}{2}<x<\frac{5\pm3}{2}$$

Possible solutions:

$2<x<1$ (not valid)

$2<x<4$ (ok)

$3<x<1$ (not valid)

$3<x<4$ (ok, but is a subset of solution 2.

Therefore $S=\{2<x<4\}$

The only problem is that the correct solution is $S=\{1<x<2\text{ or }3<x<4\}$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hint: what happens when you take square roots in an inequality and consider both the positive and negative root. For example, $1<4<9$, but taking square roots, $\pm 1<2<\pm 3$ gives something fishy. Afterall, if say $-1<0$ but squaring both sides does not preserve the inequality: $1<0$.

Comment: The double inequality $$\frac{25-24}{4}<\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2<\frac{25-16}{4}$$ is not equivalent to
$$\frac{\pm\sqrt1}{\sqrt4}<\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2}<\frac{\pm\sqrt9}{\sqrt4}$$

Comment: Why not? If I had them separated (like equation 1 and 2) wouldn't it be valid? I'm not questioning your math, I'm just trying to grasp it.

Comment: @Luiz Borges Well, $\sqrt{\left( x-\frac{5}{2}\right) ^{2}}\geq 0$ and $\frac{-\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{4}}<0$; and similarly for the first inequality.

Comment: @LuizBorges The solution is $1<x<2$ or $3<x<4$. Proof. The solution of the first inequality $x^{2}-5x+4<0$ is $1<x<4$, because the roots of $x^{2}-5x+4=0$ are $x_{1}=1$ and $x_{2}=4$, and the coefficient of $x^{2}$ is positive. The solution of the second inequality $x^{2}-5x+6>0$ is $x<2$ or $x>3$, because the roots of $x^{2}-5x+6=0$ are $x_{1}=2$ and $x_{2}=3$, and the coefficient of $x^{2}$ is positive.

Comment: @LuizBorges The correct equivalence is

$$\frac{1}{4}<\left( x-\frac{5}{2}\right) ^{2}<\frac{9}{4}\Leftrightarrow 
\frac{1}{2}<\left\vert x-\frac{5}{2}\right\vert <\frac{3}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a $\pm$ on each side of the inequality, but you need to change the *direction of inequality* for the "minus".

So you would have $$\dfrac{5 + 1}{2} < x < \dfrac{5+3}{2}$$
(The $+$'s go together), or $$\dfrac{5 - 1}{2} > x > \dfrac{5 - 3}{2}$$
(The $-$'s go together)

Comment: I did reached that by trial analysis, but why is that? I'm trying to run away from "magic rules"... :(

Comment: See Phira's answer, which I will now comment on.

Comment: I got it know. I will accept your answer, but it could be Phira as well. I got choose one. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime. Maybe I'll have a look at her other answers and find a few I haven't voted on :)

Comment: @LuizBorges: It's not a "magic rule", it's the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, not $\pm x$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I refered to: _change the direction of inequality for the "minus"._ What I had missed, is that $|x|=|y|$ is equivalent of saying just $|x|=y$ (the other cases are implied). But when I have a situation like $|x|=|y|=|z|$ I can't imply just two cases. This is where I was wrong.

Comment: @Luiz: I actually disagree. Once you had $$\frac{25-24}{4}<\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2<\frac{25-16}{4}$$ when you take square roots you get $$\frac{1}{2}\lt \left|x-\frac{5}{2}\right|\lt \frac{3}{2}.$$ That's what Americo was saying above. This triple inequality *is* equivalent to the triple inequality before it. You don't have three (or two) absolute values, you just have one. Incorrectly identifying your error is just going to lead to *more* errors.

Comment: Hum... I think I understand it better now. I'm not at home now, so tomorrow I will sit with pencil and paper and try it out separating the two equations to visualize what you're saying, but I guess I'm almost there. Square roots and absolute values are much worser and counterintuive than I thought.

Answer (score 6):

When you take the root of an inequality, you have to make sure that everything is positive and then take positive roots.

So after taking the roots, you get:

$\frac 12 < |x-\frac 52| < \frac 32$.

Now, you can regard the two cases $x> \frac 52$ and $x < \frac 52$ to eliminate the absolute value.

Comment: (For Luiz) - When $x > \dfrac{5}{2}$, the absolute value can be dropped. This gives the first inequality in my answer. When $x < \dfrac{5}{2}$, you must multiply everything by $-1$, giving the second inequality in my answer.